# How to create formula field where i have to add 6 months to one date field?

Tags: formula, administration

I have one date field DOJ(date of joining). I have to create one formula field "CONFIRMATION DATE" where the date value will be DOJ+ 6months( whenever i enter some data in DOJ field). So how to do that any suggestions...

Comment: This may be helpful: [how do I add 6 months to a date field in a formula](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ghlIAAQ)

Comment: (DOJ__C+ 6) try this one

Answer (score 2):

There is one good formula in the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm) :

(assuming your DOJ API name is DOJ__c)

```
DATE(
  YEAR( DOJ__c ) + FLOOR( ( MONTH ( DOJ__c ) + 6 - 1 ) / 12 ),
  MOD( MONTH ( DOJ__c ) + 6 - 1 + 
    IF( DAY ( DOJ__c ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( DOJ__c ) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1, 
      2, 28,
      4, 30,
      6, 30,
      9, 30, 
      11, 30,
      31 ), 1, 0 ), 12 ) + 1,
    IF( DAY( DOJ__c ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( DOJ__c ) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1,
      2, 28, 
      4, 30, 
      6, 30, 
      9, 30, 
      11, 30, 
      31 ), 
    1, DAY( DOJ__c )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank u. this code helped

```
DATE( 
   YEAR( DOJ__c )
   + FLOOR(6+ MONTH( DOJ__c ) )  / 12
     -  IF (MOD(MONTH(DOJ__c)+6,12)=0,1,0)


   ,MOD((6 + MONTH( DOJ__c )-1 ),12)+1 
   ,DAY( DOJ__c )
  )
```